# SlideToggle multiple divs in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have this type of layout:

```
+---------------+
|  hide/show    | <-- button
+---------------+
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 1 | | 2 | | 3 | <- widgets
+---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 4 | | 5 | | 6 | 
+---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+
| 7 | | 8 | | 9 | 
+---+ +---+ +---+
```

Within each widget, i have a 'close button':

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                        \ /|
|  HEADING                                X |  <--'close widget' button
|                                        / \|
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                          _/
|     CONTENT                          ___/
|                              _______/    
|                   __________/                                                      
|                  /           
|_________________/
```

---

## Main Issue

---

I am using Jquery's 'toggle' effect to achieve this.

However, the big button (`Hide/Show`) is used to hide/show **all** of them. (all hidden, all shown)

I can't seem to work out how to do this :(

Currently i have [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keux0g25/1/) showing if I close a couple of them, and hit the toggle all button, it will close the rest on screen, and show the one's i've just closed (not wanted).

I want this button to show all (or hide all) depending on if

> - (a) they are all hidden, then show all or
> - (b) if some are hidden, then show them.
> - (c) if all are shown, then hide all.

How can I get this functionality?

---

## Side Issue

*(wanted but not necessarily required)*

---

On the 'show', how can I get them to show div1 first, then div2, then div3/etc until all are shown?
(i.e. toggle them in sequence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `slideToggle()` doesn't care about the state of each individual widget, you're going to have to manually keep track of whether all widgets should be open or closed -- thereby defeating the purpose of using `slideToggle()`!

```
$('#widgetToggle').on('click', function () {
    var $widgets = $('.widget');
    if ($widgets.filter(':visible').length == $widgets.length) {
        $widgets.slideUp();
    } else {
        showInSequence($widgets.filter(':hidden'));
    }
    return false;
});

function showInSequence($el) {
    if ($el.length) {
        $el.first().slideDown(function () {
            showInSequence($el.filter(':hidden'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops -- had `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. Corrected.

Comment: thank you for your answer/input. I was actually trying to implement a mix between your answer and Yury's when he posted the update, solving the slight bug. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if it still matters, but your accepted answer also hides them in sequence, which is not exactly what you asked for.

Comment: yeah, I know - i've actually been reading up on jquery to find out how to fix that - I see you've made an edit so i'll have to look at it and see if/how you do it

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$('#widgetToggle').click(function () {
    var widgets = $('.widget'),
        total = widgets.length,
        visible = widgets.filter(':visible').length,
        //hide if all are visible
        method = total === visible ? 'slideUp': 'slideDown', 
        run = function() {
            var first;
            if(widgets.length) { //there is something left               
                first = widgets.first(); //save first
                widgets = widgets.slice(1); //remove processed
                first[method](run); //show hide
            }
        };

    run();
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/keux0g25/7/).

Comment: This is (almost) exactly what i'm looking for! I've only tested it in chrome, but 'closing' div 1,6,9 and 'showing' them again is perfect apart from div 9 not showing?

Comment: `widgets.first()[method](run);` -- love this!

Comment: @jbutler483 Fixed. Need to remove item from the collection before running next animation. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help. Just goes to show how much I need to learn about JQuery! (I didn't even know there was a **.filter** :)